# Django CSRF cookie sending images with axios client

Tags: python, django, axios

Good day.

I need to send an image by the post method of a client with axios to a Django server but I get the following message on the server.

> Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.):

And the client gives me the following answer

> xhr.js:177 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/xxxx/ 403 (Forbidden)

How is it possible to solve this problem? It is possible to disable the CSRF cookie=

This is the client code:

```
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("imagen", await fetch(`${filepath}`).then((e) => {
        return e.blob()
        })
        .then((blob) => {
            let b: any = blob
            b.lastModifiedDate = new Date()
            b.name = ''
            return b as File
        })
     );

    const axios = require('axios');
   
    axios({
        url:url,
        method:'POST',
        data:formData
    }).then(function(res: any){
        console.log(res)
    
    }).catch((error: any) =>{
        console.log(error)
       //Network error comes in
    });
```

And this is the server view function (It just check the info to debug)

```
def completeInfo (request): 
   print(request)
   return HttpResponse("Bad Response")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had faced similar issue and using `@csrf_exempt` solved my problem.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt 
def completeInfo (request): 
   print(request)
   return HttpResponse("Bad Response")
```

Comment: Your solution is good as well. And if you want to keep the csrf security, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66027435/1031191

Comment: Thanks. That solution is the one I want to implement but what I get is this: Import "django.views.decorators.csrf" could not be resolved from sourcePylance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the csrf checking, you'll need to supply it with the headers:

in your template:

```
<script>
  var csrfToken = "{{ csrf_token|escapejs }}";
</script>
```

then in your axios call:

```
axios({
    url:url,
    method:'POST',
    data:formData,
    headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken }
})
```

and on the django side, settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE += ['django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware']
```